# Cannot enter the (existing) built-in-functions tag

Tags: support, tagging, design, questions

It just happened to me when asking [a question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124458/35000).

I wanted to add the built-in functions tag to my question. When I start typing it, this appears as an option, although I cannot choose it. Still, when I finish typing it, the words transform themselves into the [built-in-functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/built-in-functions) tag. However when I post the question, this tag turns into the [built-in-symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/built-in-symbols) tag by some reason. I believe this must be considered as a bug, no?

Comment: The two tags were recently synonymized.

Comment: @J.M. I see. Still I think it is misleading for the uninitiated, when the second one appears as an option and then unexpectedly changes into the first one. Besides, if you look into the question I tried to tag, I believe [tag:built-in-symbols] is not so appropriate there, unlike [tag:built-in-functions].

Comment: (1) That's how synonyms work on SE sites. I doubt there's much one can do about it. (2) From a *Mathematica* point of view, while there are a few built-in symbols that are not functions (e.g `Pi`, many option names, etc.), all built-in functions are built-in symbols. So it's a distinction without much of a difference. I'll edit the tag wiki to clarify.

Comment: It has always been a mechanism of SE that you are free to enter a synonym tag, but that is then changed to the main synonym upon posting. (And as Michael notes, in the *Mathematica* context at least, "functions" are a subset of "symbols".)

Comment: @J.M. Is this behavior documented (in a way it would be easy to notice)?